# Hibernate one-to-one unidirectional: IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have one-to-one mapping between two tables:

**person** -> id | name

**person_status** -> id | person_id | status

I'm following the [hibernate user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one) to create a one-to-one unidirectional mapping.
If we want lazy association, they [say](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional-lazy):

> ...it’s much more efficient to use unidirectional @OneToOne associations with the @MapsId annotation in place.

But they don't provide an example for this. I tried the following, but getting the following exception while saving a record:

**org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class PersonStatusEntity**

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
class PersonEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    val name: String,

    @OneToOne(
        //mappedBy = "person", //removed because I don't want bidirectional
        cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        optional = false,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    var personStatus: PersonStatusEntity
)
```

```
@Entity(name = "PersonStatus")
class PersonStatusEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    var person: PersonEntity? = null,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    val status: Status
)
```

I also tried removing `@GeneratedValue()` without any luck.

Comment: This question kind of duplicates your original one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74063093/hibernate-one-to-one-unidirectional-puts-null-in-foreign-key/74100897#74100897

Answer (score 0):

As written in your code:

```
removed because I don't want bidirectional
```

If you really need unidirectional association, remove completely block

```
@OneToOne(
    //mappedBy = "person", //removed because I don't want bidirectional
    cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    optional = false,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
var personStatus: PersonStatusEntity
```

And leave OneToMany in PersonStatus only.

Also GeneratedValue should be removed in PersonStatus, because you trying to use shared PK using MapsId annotation.

Note: If you think, that you need unidirectional association, so, you should add **mappingBy** on the PersonEntity side. Also note, that only one side of unidirectional side will be really lazy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to access personStatus from person, not the other way round. Also pls note that the foreign key person_id is inside person_status table.